# Let $M_a$ be a multiplication operator ($M_a u = a(x) u(x)$) and $a \in L_{\infty} (\Omega)$. Show, that $\|M_a\| = \|a\|_{\infty}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

There's a hint:

We need to use

$$\Omega_{\varepsilon} = \left\{  x \in \Omega \ : \ |a(x)| > \|a\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon \right\}$$

which is of positive measure, and what we have to do is to write out $\|M_a u_{\varepsilon}\|$ where $u_{\varepsilon} = u \chi_{\Omega_{\varepsilon}}$

I don't really know what to do. If we write out this norm, we get eventually: $$\|M_a u_{\varepsilon}\| > (\|a\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon) \|u_{\varepsilon}\|$$

So what am I supposed to do? We can't do something like $$\|a\|_{\infty} \|u_{\varepsilon}\| \ge \|M_a u_{\varepsilon}\| > (\|a\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon) \|u_{\varepsilon}\|$$

and take $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, because we'll get a contradiction because of that "$>$" (and also, $\Omega_{\varepsilon} \rightarrow \varnothing$ because no value $|a(x)|$ is greater than the supremum norm).

Answer (score 2):

The point is the other inequality is more obvious:
$$
\|M_a u\|_p^p=\int_\Omega|a|^p|u|^p\leq \|a\|_\infty^p\|u\|_p^p.
$$
Now, with the hint, for given $\epsilon>0$, you can find an element in $L^p$ (be careful with the possibility that $\mu(\Omega_\epsilon)=+\infty$ if $\Omega$ is not of finite measure) with $$\|M_au_\epsilon\|> (\|a\|_\infty-\epsilon)\|u_\epsilon\|$$
so that $\|a\|_\infty$ is in fact the supremum in the definition of the operator norm.

Edit: Some more details follow. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $u_\epsilon=\chi_{\Omega_\epsilon}$ and note that $u_\epsilon$ is nonzero as an element in $L^p$ since $\mu(\Omega_\epsilon)>0$. Then, by the definition of the operator norm as a supremum,
$$
\|M_a\|\geq\frac{\|M_au_\epsilon\|}{\|u_\epsilon\|}> \|a\|_\infty-\epsilon.
$$
Now, since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we can take $\epsilon\to 0$ in the inequality
$$
\|M_a\|>\|a\|_\infty-\epsilon
$$
and conclude $\| M_a\|\geq \|a\|_\infty$

Comment: Right, now I see it. We just take such $u_{\varepsilon}$ that its norm is equal to $1$. But still, I don't understand why we even can take the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, because as I pointed out, $\Omega_{\varepsilon} = \varnothing$

Comment: But still another question: If I take such $u_{\varepsilon}$ that its norm is equal to 1, how do you suddenly get $\ge$ instead of $>$?

Comment: You don't need to actually take a formal limit in $\epsilon$ (although taking limits does make strict inequalities into not strict inequalities!), the point is just that you show that a quantity $c\geq a-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, which shows $c\geq a$ (suppose not....)

Comment: I don't see why $c \ge a$ if $c \ge a - \varepsilon$. Definitely, it's true that $c \ge a \ge a - \varepsilon$. But we only know that $c > a - \varepsilon$

Comment: What I mean is why can we say  (if $\|u_{\varepsilon}\| = 1$) that $\|M_a u_{\varepsilon} \| > \|a\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon$ implies that  $\|M_a u_{\varepsilon} \| \ge \|a\|_{\infty} $

Comment: @anon ok, I will add some more detail

Comment: We have the inequality $\|M_a\| > \|a\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon$ now. Why, if we take the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, can we conclude that  $\|M_a\| \ge \|a\|_{\infty}$? What I don't understand is the transition from "$>$" to "$\ge$"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136749/discussion-between-operatorerror-and-anon).